# RUBY - Find the most common medicine name in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to get the most frequent medicine name in the array of hashes.

The array data is:

```
Medicine.create([{name: "Apixibucil", patient_id: 1, review_id: 17, nurse_id: 2},
  {name: "Adriacilin", patient_id: 1, review_id: 17, nurse_id: 12},
  {name: "Tiaferol", patient_id: 4, review_id: 2, nurse_id: 17},
  {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 6, review_id: 7, nurse_id: 10},
  {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 9, review_id: 9, nurse_id: 9},
  {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 22, review_id: 13, nurse_id: 1}])
```

The code that I have written is (The method is part of a CLI, that's why I included it):

```
def most_common_medicine_on_study
  puts "Do you want to know the most popular medicine in the study?"
  puts ">"
  input = gets.chomp
  if input == "yes" || "y"
    Medicine["data"].each do |meds|
      meds["name"].max_by {|name| name.length}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a rails application and the Medicine class inheriting from ActiveRecord?

Comment: What is `Medicine`? What is `create`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a valid Ruby array:

```
medicine = [{name: "Apixibucil", patient_id: 1, review_id: 17, nurse_id: 2},
            {name: "Adriacilin", patient_id: 1, review_id: 17, nurse_id: 12},
            {name: "Tiaferol", patient_id: 4, review_id: 2, nurse_id: 17},
            {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 6, review_id: 7, nurse_id: 10},
            {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 9, review_id: 9, nurse_id: 9},
            {name: "Afalinum", patient_id: 22, review_id: 13, nurse_id: 1}]
```

You can do using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) an [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
medicine.group_by{ |h| h[:name] }.transform_values { |v| v.size}.max_by { |_, v| v }
```

Or using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) using [`Hash#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) default to 0, in order to count:

```
medicine.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, o| o[h[:name]] += 1 }.max_by { |_, v| v }
```

Both ways uses [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to get the max count, returning:

```
["Afalinum", 3]
```

---

If you are using Rails check [calculations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html), maybe you can do:

```
Medicine.group(:name).count
# => { 'Apixibucil' => 1, 'Adriacilin' => 1, 'Tiaferol' => 1, 'Afalinum' => 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
Medicine['data'].reduce Hash.new(0) do |count, med|
  count[med[:name]] += 1
  count
end.max_by(&:last)

#=> ["Afalinum", 3]
```

1) Reduce a hash where all values default to 0.

2) Count the occurrence of each med name.

3) Return the largest count from the counter.

#### Benchmarked

To give everyone an idea of where performance runs for the proposed approaches here are the outputs for both speed and memory usage. To run the test, I duplicated the data to have around 3,000,000 entries.

```
benchmarker do
  result = data.reduce Hash.new(0) do |count, med|
    count[med[:name]] += 1
    count
  end.max_by(&:last)

  puts result
end
#=> [Afalinum, 1500000]
#=> {"ruby":"2.5.1","elapsed_time":0.72,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"0 MB","garbage_collection_count":1}

benchmarker do
  result = data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, o| o[h[:name]] += 1 }.max_by { |_, v| v }

  puts result
end
#=> [Afalinum, 1500000]
#=> {"ruby":"2.5.1","elapsed_time":0.72,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"0 MB","garbage_collection_count":1}

benchmarker do
  result = data.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.transform_values { |v| v.size}.max_by { |_, v| v }

  puts result
end
#=> [Afalinum, 1500000]
#=> {"ruby":"2.5.1","elapsed_time":0.52,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"18 MB","garbage_collection_count":2}
```

I found it interesting to see that the `group_by` approach actually handled the computation faster, though used up a fair amount of memory to do so. The first to performed literally the same, leaving it up to the developer to choose which they find more readable.

Comment: This is a trivial and inferior variation of @iGan's answer that uses `Enumerable#each_with_object` and `Hash::new`.

Comment: Please, Cary... explain.

Comment: You've simply used `reduce` rather than `each_with_object`. To use the latter you need only flip the order of the block variables and eliminate the line `count`. I said "inferior" because `each_was_object` does not require that pesky line `"count"`.

Comment: You're right @CarySwoveland that they are comparable. The reason I chose to share the method I did was that I felt that it was more readable, even with the pesky "count" line... I updated my response to show benchmarks for each method's performance, which shows both the `each_with_object` and `reduce` technique to be completely comparable - making it a stylistic choice.